# Trim Vector White Spaces While Denoting Elements If they are Blank Should be NAs

Tags: r, string, tidyr, data-cleaning

I'm dealing with a data cleaning issue resulting from web scraping.  It's an edge case but here is a sample of the initial table:

```
""                                                      ""                                                     
 [3] ""                                                      ""                                                     
 [5] ""                                                      "Fund Management"                                      
 [7] "Fund SponsorMassachusetts Financial Services"          "Portfolio ManagersGeoffrey L. Schechter (30 Dec 2004)"
 [9] ""                                                      ""                                                     
[11] "Basics"                                                ""                                                     
[13] "Category:"                                             "Tax-Free Income-High Yield"                           
[15] "Ticker:"                                               "MFM       "                                           
[17] "NAV Ticker:"                                           "XMFMX"                                                
[19] "Average Daily Volume (shares):"                        ""                                                     
[21] "Average Daily Volume (USD):"                           "M"                                                    
[23] "Inception Date:"                                       "11/25/1986"                                           
[25] "Inception Share Price:"                                "$10.00"                                               
[27] "Inception NAV:"                                        "$9.40"                                                
[29] "Tender Offer:"                                         "No"                                                   
[31] "Term:"                                                 "No"                                                   
[33] "Fiscal Year End:"                                      "October 31"                                           
[35] "Third Party Links & Reports"                           ""                                                     
[37] "SEC Filings"                                           "Intraday Pricing"                                     
[39] "Fund Sponsor Website "                                 ""                                                     
[41] ""                                                      ""                                                     
[43] ""                                                      ""                                                     
[45] ""                                                      ""
```

The issue is I would like to be able to trim white spaces on the borders of the table (i.e. elements 1-4 and 40-45 BUT if there's a blank in an element following an element with string and a ":" that shouldn't be trimmed but rather have an NA put in place instead.  I'm trying to prepare this vector in a dynamic way so that it doesn't require constant monitoring in the event the web page's formatting changes slightly.  Thanks!

See dput:

c("", "", "", "", "", "Fund Management", "Fund SponsorMassachusetts Financial Services", 
"Portfolio ManagersGeoffrey L. Schechter (30 Dec 2004)", "", 
"", "Basics", "", "Category:", "Tax-Free Income-High Yield", 
"Ticker:", "MFM       ", "NAV Ticker:", "XMFMX", "Average Daily Volume (shares):", 
"", "Average Daily Volume (USD):", "M", "Inception Date:", "11/25/1986", 
"Inception Share Price:", "$10.00", "Inception NAV:", "$9.40", 
"Tender Offer:", "No", "Term:", "No", "Fiscal Year End:", "October 31", 
"Third Party Links & Reports", "", "SEC Filings", "Intraday Pricing", 
"Fund Sponsor Website ", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")

However, vector is a character vector and not a list.

Comment: Can you share the `dput` of your data and update the post with your expected output?

Comment: something like `replace(x <- trimws(c("", "Term")), x=="", NA_character_)`

Comment: sort of parallel: `library(tidyverse); na_if(str_trim(x), '')`

Comment: I'm not looking to transform all blanks to NA's just the blanks following string which includes a colon.

Comment: This should work for the NAs but I don't really know what you mean by trim here : `x[c(FALSE, grepl(":$",head(x,-1))) & x == ""] <- NA`